# How to add Text Input Filter to custom module (hidden column)

Tags: filter, magento2.4

I am trying to add a custom filter to a custom module in admin grid, however I do not want that column to be shown therefore I have tried both ways by adding a column and making `visible` field to `false` and adding `<filterInput` to filters field but I do not see the filter in the filter grid.

What I want is a text filter which searches `LIKE` data and if matches the result then shows those certain records.

**Filter field:**

```
 <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters_modifier" xsi:type="array"/>
                    </item>
                    <item name="observers" xsi:type="array"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <statefull>
                    <property name="applied" xsi:type="boolean">false</property>
                </statefull>
            </settings>
            <filterInput name="column_name" sortOrder="100" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <label translate="true">Text</label>
                    <dataScope>column_name</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </filterInput>
        </filters>
```

**Column field:**

```
<column name="column_name" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="35">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/text</bodyTmpl>
                <label translate="true">NAME</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

I have also tried to remove `visible` field but nothing shows.

Comment: What happens when you make the column visible? Is filter is getting displayed? If yes than you can simply disable it to be shown in grid from backend.

Comment: @RahulBarot neither the column visible nor the filter, if i change visible to `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to display column in grid then no need to write code there. Please comment it or just remove code from it.

In below code i have shown "product_name" column only in filter and not showing in grid.

Please update code like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">zealousweb_custom_custom_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="custom_record_custom_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <!-- here we pass dataprovider name which i will define in di.xml file of module in next step -->
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.zealousweb_custom_custom_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataCustomActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.zealousweb_custom_custom_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.zealousweb_custom_custom_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <captionValue>0</captionValue>
                    <options class="Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options"/>
                    <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                    <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
            <filterInput name="product_name" sortOrder="100" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <label translate="true">Product Name</label>
                    <dataScope>product_name</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </filterInput>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.zealousweb_custom_custom_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your custom-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="custom/custom/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.zealousweb_custom_custom_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <!-- from here we'll add columns of custom list -->
    <columns name="zealousweb_custom_custom_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">custom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.zealousweb_custom_custom_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">zealousweb_custom_columnscustom_record_custom_list.custom_record_custom_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <!-- <column name="product_name" class="Zealousweb\Custom\Ui\Component\Listing\Custom\Column\ProductActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column> -->
        <column name="product_sku">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Sku</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```